# How to use multithreading with a queue (ish)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm currently crawling our websites with a simple python script.
Basically, the code looks like this:

```
urls_to_check = ['site1.example.com', 'site2.example.com']
checked_urls = []

while len(urls_to_check) > 0:
    url_to_check = urls_to_check.pop()

    current_result = check_url(url_to_check) # Returns info on the page as well as a list of external links found on the page
    checked_urls.append(current_result)
    for url in current_result.external_links:
        urls_to_check.append(url)
```

This process works fine but is quite slow. Therefore, I'd like to use multithreading in order to speed things up.

I have found plenty of articles on using multithreading or multiprocessing but they all relate to a closed number of things to do (`for i in range(0,5)` type of loop), but nothing with a *moving target* like a queue.

would someone have a pointer to the right direction?

Comment: Are you willing to use other tools like `Scrapy`, or you want to stick to the `multithreading` way?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Sorry about the edition. I'm not looking for a way to scrape the page (I already have the logic and the custom actions). I'm only looking for a way to parallelise the execution.

Comment: `Scrapy` has everything you need for this specific tasks to accomplish, so I'd recommend to take a look at it.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for the tip! I'll definitely look into it